Extract query text in Teradata , from dbc.dbqlsqltbl
I'm trying to extract a query text from
dbc.dbqlsqltbl.
My goal is to extract the query text using export file in bteq , and then execute the query using run file.
for example:
.export report file = filename.sql
select sqltextinfo from dbc.dbqlsqltbl where queryid = \<number\>
.export reset
.run file = filename.sql

The query text is stored in the field sqltextinfo as a single row, and in some cases it generates some difficulties.
For example if the original query is
select field1, field2 --some comment
from table1;

in filename.sql I will find
select field1, field2 --some comment from table1;
The "run file" generates the execution error :
Failed [3822 : 42S22] Cannot resolve column 'field1'. Specify table or view.
Is it possible to extract the query with the rigth "wrap text" ?

Multiple problems with this.  You've hit the first already, the entire query comes back as an unformatted string, so you lose line breaks.  You might be able to get around that if you treat the column in BTEQ as a CLOB, although that may bring more headaches.

To change this behavior, use .SET TRANSLATECTRLSTOSPACES OFF - and if you are using EXPORT REPORT for this you likely also want to set FORMAT and TITLEDASHES off and set the WIDTH much wider than the default. But EXPORT DATA may be a better choice for this use case.
